# Mocha test doesn't call .then from function call

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have tested this over and over again trying to figure out a solution but cannot. I have tried Googling everything and couldn't find any that produced any results. I am using mocha module only. The problem is that when ever I run my tests its not calling the .then statement inside my functions at all. I have tested the methods outside of the test script with console.log(); and they perform as desired.

Here is the test with two comments.

```
it('Should pass if the currently set frame name is top_page', function () {

    chromeDriver.get('http://www.site_with_frame.com');

    frameHandler.switchToFrame('top_page');

    frameHandler.getCurrentFrameName(function (name) {
        console.log(name); //This is never called.
        done(); //Should this be here?
    });
});
```

Here is the function that I am calling with the callback

```
this.getCurrentFrameName = function(callback) {

    //This is called once in test
    console.log('getCurrentFrameName function '); 

    driver.executeScript('return self.name').then(function(name) 
    {
        //This is never called in test
        console.log('getCurrentFrameName .then '); 
        return callback(name);
    });
};
```

Comment: you need to be passing done at the top level function (ie it(..., function(done) { - check the async code section of the mocha docs: https://mochajs.org/ - and yes your done invocation is in the right place.

Comment: @gabdallah I have added done as you said and I receive an error Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:215:19)

Comment: You need to edit this question to show an [mcve]. If I use your code, it does not work but it fails in a way which is different from what you show in the question. So, to avoid people just guessing possible problems, make the question a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. I had to include done as an argument and then specify the timeout and done function call.

```
describe('FrameHandler', function () {
   it('Should pass if the currently set frame name is top_page', function (done) {
      this.timeout(15000); // Include this
      chromeDriver.get('http://www.site_with_frame.com');

      frameHandler.switchToFrame('top_page');

      frameHandler.getCurrentFrameName(function (name) {
      console.log(name); //This is never called.
      done(); //Include this
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: It seems you missing `done` in the `it('Should pass if the currently set frame name is top_page', function (done) {`?